# Trouble installing Vim plugins on Mac Lion

Tags: macos, unix, vim, plugins

I have unsuccessfully been trying to install some plugins for VIM for sometime. I have mostly been following the information in this [reference](https://superuser.com/questions/404686/installing-plugins-in-vim). I've basically just been dropping the plugin files in various directories hoping something works, nothing has yet. I have a .vim directory at the following path:

```
/Users/{my_user_name}/.vim
```

I have tried adding my files to the directory above as well as a directory inside it called plugins. Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

When I enter

```
:help 'rtp'
```

I get

```
 Unix: "$HOME/.vim,
 $VIM/vimfiles,
 $VIMRUNTIME,
 $VIM/vimfiles/after,
 $HOME/.vim/after"
 Amiga: "home:vimfiles,
 $VIM/vimfiles,
 $VIMRUNTIME,
 $VIM/vimfiles/after,
 home:vimfiles/after"
 PC, OS/2: "$HOME/vimfiles,
 $VIM/vimfiles, 
 $VIMRUNTIME,
 $VIM/vimfiles/after,
 $HOME/vimfiles/after"
 Macintosh: "$VIM:vimfiles,
 $VIMRUNTIME,
 $VIM:vimfiles:after"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For an hypothetical single-file plugin:

```
~/.vim/plugin/plugin.vim
```

For an hypothetical multi-file plugin:

```
~/.vim/autoload/plugin.vim
~/.vim/plugin/plugin.vim
~/.vim/doc/plugin.txt
```

If that hypothetical multi-file plugin comes with documentation, run the following command to add it to the `:help` index:

```
:helptags ~/.vim/doc
```

The `:scriptnames` shows you a list of sourced scripts.

Also, most plugins have some kind of `README` that details recommended installation procedures: read it.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I don't understand your multi file example. Are you saying the same plugin.vim file should go in both .vim/autoload and .vim/plugin? Also I don't have a .vim/autoload folder is this somehthing I should just create? I'm trying to install a debugger plugin and it has the files debugger.vim and debugger.py

Comment: No. Every plugin has its own file structure that you must respect when you install it: if it has an `autoload` directory and you don't, just copy that directory to `~/.vim`; if it doesn't, then don't bother. My example is "hypothetical" because you failed to tell us about the plugin you are trying to install.

Comment: Okay I was able to get a different plugin working by putting the .vim files in the .vim/plugin directory. How ever I am still having trouble installing my plugin with the .vim and .py files. Should I not be putting the .py file in the plugin directory?

Comment: As I said in my previous comment, you must respect the plugin's file structure but answering your question would be a lot easier if you accepted to point us to the plugin you want to install. But, somehow, you don't seem to want to so my help stops here. Good luck.

Comment: This is a link to the specific plugin http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2508

Answer (score 1):

The correct location is in a `plugin` subdirectory (not the plural `plugins`):

```
/Users/{my_user_name}/.vim/plugin/*.vim
```

You can check your actually used path with

```
:set rtp?
```

The trailing `?` means *query value, don't set*. (`:help rtp` is just the general documentation, not what's actually used.)

The useful `:scriptnames` command will tell you what actually got sourced.

Note that all these instructions are valid for plain `*.vim` plugin scripts; some plugins are also distributed as (`*.zip`, or `*.tar.gz`) archives, or the Vim-specific *Vimball* (`*.vba`, `*.vmb`), which typically contain the subdirectory structure already.

Comment: Hi Ingo thanks for your response. when I run :set rtp? I get runtimepath=~/.vim,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim73,/usr/share/vim
/vimfiles/after,~/.vim/after. Which of these paths is where the extension is supposed to go? Also some of these folders don't exist should I just create them?

Comment: The first (`~/.vim`; it should correspond to `/Users/{my_user_name}`) is for your user configuration, put it there, as shown in my answer. The other locations are for system-provided plugins that come with Vim; you shoudn't touch them, as they get overwritten on updates.